# How get information from Web page (Android)?

Tags: java, android, http, httpcontext

I make Android application which must receive data from the page http://example.com/get.php?id=1. For this I use the following method:

```
private String getData()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); // !!! application stops here
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://example.com/get.php?id=1");
        HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        String result = "";

        BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                      response.getEntity().getContent()
                    )
                  );
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        String line = null;
        try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                  result += line + "\n";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        // Now you have the whole HTML loaded on the result variable
        return result;
    }
```

I also added a permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.repetitor_ent_free"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The problem is that when I run the application on the device I get the error:
An unexpected stop the application MyApp (process com.android.myapp). Please try again.

Comment: Try to logcat it. I got error (in the sdk api >5) if the network is used in the main thread, maybe it is.

Comment: Post the Logcat output to ease the debugging.

Comment: check the logcat. You will find an exception there, and then post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, if you would like the better solution try to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). For more about threads look at '[processes and threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html)' (please, read this guide carefully to avoid this issue in future).

For example you could try one of these solutions:

1) Use the Roman's answer and add something like this:

```
final StringBuilder sb = ... ;
final TextView tv = ... ;

tv.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv.setText(sb.toString());
        }
    });
```

or use activity method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final StringBuilder sb = ... ;
        final TextView tv = ... ;

        tv.setText(sb.toString());
    }
});
```

2) Use AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> () {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... none) {
        //
        // your code
        //

        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... none) {}
    protected void onPostExecute(Void none) {
        // use this to set the text

        final StringBuilder sb = ... ;
        final TextView tv = ... ;

        tv.setText(sb.toString());              
    }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
new Thread(){
    @Owerride
    public void run(){
        URL url = new URL(urlString); 
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);sb.append("\n");
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Apparently the method works, but when I add to the end of text output that the application ends:
TextView questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.myTextView); myTextView.setText(sb.toString());

Comment: Does you add myTextView.setText(sb.toString()) inside thread?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;

try {

    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/get.php?id=1");
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    conn.connect();

    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

    //Do what you need with the data here

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle your exceptions
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
            conn = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same problem, but an exception is triggered.

Comment: Ah, didn't spot the pastebin link. Are you running this network code in the main activity ? It would need to reside in another thread to avoid blocking or Aysync task as suggested by @m039